# Displaying Text in a Formview Label while in Edit Mode

Tags: c#, formview

I have a Formview which is in EditMode by default and that has no other mode template added. I need to write to a Label within that Formview.

```
    FileUpload Upload = (FileUpload)Formview_EditProcessData.FindControl("FileUpload2");
    Label Log = (Label)Formview_EditProcessData.FindControl("LoadLog2");
    if (Upload.HasFile)
        try
        {
            if (Upload.PostedFile.ContentType != "image/svg+xml")
            {
                Log.Text = "Wrong Filetype!;
                Log.ForeColor =  System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                return;
            }
            Upload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~/"+ Upload.FileName));
            MessageBox.Text = "File successfully uploaded!";
            Log.Text = "File successfully uploaded!";
```

The weird thing in my code is, that this works while displaying the error ("Wrong Filetype!") but does not for the "File successfully uploaded!". I do send this message to a Label (MessageBox) outside the Formview and there everything is displayed as expected.

This seems so illogical to me!

--

I found a workaround by defining the Formview's Label in the same way as above, but this time at the very end. I assigning the error messages to an invisible Label outside the Formview and set the Log's content to that message content.

```
    FileUpload Upload = (FileUpload)Formview_EditProcessData.FindControl("FileUpload2");
    if (Upload.HasFile)
        try
        {
            if (Upload.PostedFile.ContentType != "image/svg+xml")
            {
                MessageBox.Text = "Wrong Filetype";
                return;
            }
            Upload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~/"+ Upload.FileName));
            MessageBox.Text = "File successfully uploaded";
    .
    .
    Label Log = (Label)Formview_EditProcessData.FindControl("LoadLog2");
    Log.Text = MessageBox.Text;
    if (Convert.ToString(MessageBox).Substring(0,4) == "File")
    {
        Log.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
```

I still do not understand why the label seems to loose it's definition after the if(Upload.PostedFile.ContentType...) condition; but at least now it's working the way I wanted